# I am looking for a step-by-step Guide to create a new Cryptocurrency, based on Bitcoin code

Tags: altcoin

I am looking for a step-by-step guide on creating a new CryptoCurrency using BitCoin Code, particularly on Fedora.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have to ask...

Comment: It seems some text got truncated